# How to define a non-null computed column in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following column in a database table:

```
FieldA   (decimal(19, 2), not null)
```

Applying the following change:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD
   Field1 AS FieldA,
   Field2 AS CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldA),
   Field3 AS CAST(FieldA AS decimal(19, 2))
```

Gives me the following new columns:

```
Field1    (Computed, decimal(19, 2), not null)
Field2    (Computed, decimal(19, 2), null)
Field3    (Computed, decimal(19, 2), null)
```

Why are `Field2` and `Field3` nullable? How to make either of them non-nullable?

Please do note that `FieldA`in `Field2`and `Field3` will be replaced with some computation on `FieldA`, thus need to use either `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` to force the type of the result.

Comment: On the one hand, computed columns are not stored and their result is only calculated on run-time of the query. And, because of your columns values are generated with `CONVERT()` and `CAST()` functions, both of which CAN return NULL values, I believe that is why your `Field2` and `Field3` columns are NULL-able. There is no guarantee from the function's perspective that the result is NOT NULL, only from the data's perspective. (Just my 2 cents, not an official answer)

Comment: **Update / Clarification**: Computed columns can be stored by using the `PERSISTED` keyword at the end of the definition of the column, but this is not the case here in OP's question.

Comment: **Update 2 - [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)**: "NOT NULL can be specified for computed columns only if PERSISTED is also specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RaduGheorghiu Explained in their comment why the attributes are nullable. Now, to make them not nullable, I wrote this little test:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.test (id INT NOT NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD 
field1 AS id
, field2 AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), id)
, field3 AS ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), id), 0.0)
, field4 AS COALESCE(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), id), 0.0)
, field5 AS CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), id)
                 ELSE 0
            END
GO
```

This produces the following table:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| id          | int       | NO          |
| field1      | int       | NO          |
| field2      | decimal   | YES         |
| field3      | decimal   | NO          |
| field4      | decimal   | YES         |
| field5      | decimal   | YES         |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

So you can force nullability with `ISNULL`, but, rather surprisingly, not with `COALESCE` or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: I wouldn't really "bet" on `ISNULL()` as being the solution to it, at least only by looking at the `IS_NULLABLE` column. Try: `Field4 AS ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldA), CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldA)),
   Field5 AS ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldA), 0)` and see that `ISNULL` does not work the same. It gies you NON-NULLABLE because you have a fixed value as the fallback for the function, however, even though the chain of data from `fieldA` to `field5` is guaranteed to be non-nullable, the result (column definition) is not.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - this is documented "An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant), where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: In a quick testing, `field3 AS ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), id), 0.0)` seems to work for us. The type is applied to the 'null' value as well, i.e., `SELECT` shows "0.00" (2 decimals). Strange.

Answer (score 1):

While I like HoneyBadger's answer, I want to offer another possibility:
Mark the computed columns as persisted not null. ([non persisted computed columns does not support the `not null` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

This means that instead of being computed on demand (meaning, only when they are used in a select statement), the computed columns will be physically stored with the rest of the table's columns - and only gets computed when the value they rely on changes.

Persisted computed columns can only rely on constants, columns and deterministic functions - but `convert` and `cast` are deterministic, so no problem there:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    FieldA decimal(19, 2) not null
);

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD
   Field1 AS FieldA,
   Field2 AS CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldA) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
   Field3 AS CAST(FieldA AS decimal(19, 2)) PERSISTED NOT NULL;

GO

SELECT Column_Name, Is_Nullable
FROM Information_schema.Columns
WHERE Table_Name = 'MyTable'
```

Results:

```
Column_Name     Is_Nullable
FieldA          NO
Field1          NO
Field2          NO
Field3          NO
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it's worth mentioning that there is a downside, because you generate more IO and CPU usage (page updates, index updates and possibly more).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I was under the impression that it's kinda obvious when I specified that persisted computed columns are stored rather then computed on the fly - but if you think it's not obvious enough feel free to edit that in.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Personally, I think that the comments are enough, thanks!